# Calling another user command inside the user defined command

Tags: vim

Is it not possible to call another user defined command in a user defined command?

I tried the following two lines but neither of them worked:

```
command! GetRapidLinks FindRapidLinks|MatchesOnly

command! GetRapidLinks :FindRapidLinks|:MatchesOnly
```

The Vim help reads:

> You cannot use ":X", ":Next" and ":Print"

The context of this restriction is not clear. I guess one cannot use those in a user defined command, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you didn't define the `:FindRapidLinks` command with `-bar`; without it, the command "eats" the entire remaining arguments (cp. `:help command-bar`). So, either redefine:

```
:command! -bar FindRapidLinks ...
:command! GetRapidLinks FindRapidLinks|MatchesOnly
```

or work around this (for cases when you cannot redefine the other command) via `:execute`:

```
:command! GetRapidLinks execute 'FindRapidLinks'|MatchesOnly
```

As a general rule, use `-bar` unless your custom command needs to be passed arguments that contain special characters like `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what the help means is, you can't call a **user** command `:Next` or `:X`, because  those are the few builtin commands, that start with a capital letter. I am not sure, why your vim actually says, you can't define a `:Print` command, as it is possible to define your own custom `:Print` command (since the builtin command is only an alias for `:print` anyhow)

I am not sure, what exactly you are trying to achieve here, so I can't answer the first part of your question. You can however in a function or in a custom command call another custom command.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try backticks ` (not to be mistaken with quotes ' or ")

for e.g.

```
command! GetRapidLinks `FindRapidLinks` | MatchesOnly
```

or

```
command! GetRapidLinks $(FindRapidLinks) | MatchesOnly
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried both. Vim responded: E492: Not an editor command.